# Silverstripe fulltextsearch on custom field

Tags: php, full-text-search, silverstripe

I'm using Silverstripe [FullTextSearch](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-fulltextsearch). My interrogation is how search in a custom field and show results. There is code write in index.md :

File: mysite/code/MyIndex.php:

```
<?php
class MyIndex extends SolrIndex {
    function init() {
        $this->addClass('MyPage');
        $this->addFulltextField('Description');
    }
}
```

In Page.php

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    private static $allowed_actions = array('search');
    public function search($request) {
        $query = new SearchQuery();
        $query->search($request->getVar('q'));
        return $this->renderWith('array(
            'SearchResult' => singleton('MyIndex')->search($query)
        ));
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to search some words from description field, no results are found... Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience FullTextSearch has been frustrating and problematic. I am willing to be corrected, but I feel like the devs are moving away from it in place of using SearchFilters (https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/).

If it is helpful at all I wrote a module that allows for custom searching and displaying the results in a custom controller. It isn't as efficient as FullTextSearch but works pretty well (https://github.com/i-lateral/silverstripe-searchable).

I did originally try to write this module using FullTextSearch, but I just couldn't get it working.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is your search method is like partial match? ℅something℅ ? If so, its not enough to search complex words or errored words. I have already made myself a search code to get directly data from database with %something℅ and i found It not enough for my sites.

Comment: Unfortunately it does use partial match. I guess another solution would be to look into creating a custom filter that utilises full text search, or manually write the SQL using the SQLQuery class (more at https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/model/sql_query/)

Comment: Humm ok, If I found the solution, I Will post it, thanks to try to help me

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have found a solution. FullTextsearch module always search in $Title, $MenuTitle and $Content. Instead of using $Content for my content, I use $ContentPage variable. All DataObjects and other variables must must added like bellow.

Example :

```
$this->Content = $this->ContentPage." ".$this->Variable1." ".$this->Variable2." ".$dataobject;
```

In the example, all variables and dataobject in the page is searchable throught $Content. That's not a perfect solution, but works.